# numpy package not defined when importing function from another .py file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

In my master file I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
import numpy as np
import time

import sys
sys.path.append("C:/.../python check/createsplit")
import createsplit

data='MJexample'
X,Y,N,Ntr=create_training_data(data)
```

where I am calling *create_training_data* function from *createsplit.py* file which is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io

def create_training_data(data_type):
     """
     creates training data
     """
     if data_type=='MJexample':
         N=300
         Ntr = 150
         X=np.linspace(0,1,N)
         X = np.array([X,X*X,np.linspace(5,10,N),np.sin(X),np.cos(X),np.sin(X)*np.cos(X)]).T

         fac=40
         Y=np.array([np.sin(fac*x)*np.cos(fac*x**2) for x in X[:,0]])[:,None]

         _X=X
         _Y=Y
         return _X,_Y,N,Ntr
```

However running my original file results in error: **NameError: global name 'np' is not defined** for some reason I do not understand. I assume I am importing the functions in a wrong way but I don't really understand what would be wrong.

Comment: You want `X,Y,N,Ntr=createsplit.create_training_data(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue raises just because of a wrong call of the function. Try

```
X, Y, N, Ntr = createsplit.create_training_data(data)
```

instead, and it should work.